como usar o handsontable, para destroir e chamar função para reconstruir?
criei uma tabela com handsontable. e quando insiro o dado em um campo da linha ele salva no banco. porem quando coloca mais uma informação ele duplica linha ou seja, quando cria a linha com uma coluna apenas ele nao cria o id da linha pra caso venha outra infomação na linha ele atualize.. ele cria ela dnv
    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        // Função para abrir a aba e inicializar o Handsontable
        window.openTab = function(event, id) {
            console.log('Aba aberta:', id); // Adicione esta linha para verificar o id da aba ativa

            // Ocultar todas as outras abas
            const tabcontents = document.querySelectorAll('.tabcontent');
            tabcontents.forEach(content => content.style.display = 'none');

            // Exibir a aba ativa
            const activeTab = document.getElementById(id);
            activeTab.style.display = 'block';

            // Remover a classe 'active' de todos os botões
            const tablinks = document.querySelectorAll('.tablinks');
            tablinks.forEach(button => button.classList.remove('active'));

            // Adicionar a classe 'active' ao botão clicado
            const activeButton = Array.from(tablinks).find(button => button.getAttribute('onclick').includes(id));
            if (activeButton) {
                activeButton.classList.add('active');
            }

            // Inicializar Handsontable para a aba ativa, se ainda não estiver inicializado
            if (!activeTab.dataset.hotInitialized) {
                const container = activeTab.querySelector(`#tabela_${id}`);
                const hot = new Handsontable(container, {
                    licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation',
                    data: Array(1).fill([]), // Inicialmente com 1 linhas vazias
                    rowHeaders: true,
                    colHeaders: ['Data', 'Pedido', 'Quantidade', 'Peça', 'Vincular OP', 'Id'],
                    minSpareRows: 1,
                    contextMenu: true,
                    manualColumnResize: true,
                    manualRowResize: true,
                    columns: [{
                            data: 0
                        },
                        {
                            data: 1
                        },
                        {
                            data: 2
                        },
                        {
                            data: 3
                        },
                        {
                            data: 4
                        },
                        {
                            data: 5,
                            readOnly: true
                        }
                    ],
                    hiddenColumns: {
                        columns: [5],
                        indicators: false
                    },
                    colWidths: [200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 100],
                    rowHeights: 30,
                    afterChange: function(changes, source) {
                        if (source === 'edit' || source === 'paste' || source === 'autofill' || source === 'CopyPaste.paste') {
                            const changedData = hot.getData();
                            const colHeaders = hot.getColHeader();
                            const injId = id;

                            const rowsWithData = changedData.filter(row => row.some(cell => cell != null && cell.trim() !== ""));

                            // Se houver pelo menos uma linha com dados
                            if (rowsWithData.length > 0) {
                                const payload = {
                                    headers: colHeaders,
                                    data: rowsWithData, // Corrigido de completeRows para rowsWithData
                                    injId: injId
                                };

                                console.log('Payload enviado:', payload);

                                // Envia o payload para o servidor via fetch API
                                fetch('includes/salvar.php', {
                                        method: 'POST',
                                        headers: {
                                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                        },
                                        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
                                    })
                                    .then(response => response.json())
                                    .then(data => {
                                        if (data.error) {
                                            console.error('Erro ao salvar os dados:', data.error);
                                        } else {
                                            console.log('Dados salvos com sucesso:', data);

                                            // Recarregar os dados na tabela para refletir o banco de dados
                                            // hot.loadData(data);
                                            // hot.render();

                                            // // Inserir uma nova linha vazia após salvar os dados
                                            // hot.alter('insert_row', hot.countRows());
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .catch(error => console.error('Erro:', error));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Marcar que o Handsontable foi inicializado para essa aba
                activeTab.dataset.hotInitialized = true;

                // Buscar os dados e preencher a tabela
                fetch('includes/salvar.php?injId=' + id)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        console.log(data);
                        if (Array.isArray(data)) {
                            hot.loadData(data);
                            hot.render();
                        } else {
                            console.error('Dados inválidos recebidos:', data);
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.error('Erro ao buscar os dados:', error));
            }
        };

        // Abrir a primeira aba por padrão
        openTab(null, 'inj1');
    });
</script>


    
$injId = isset($_GET['injId']) ? $conexao->real_escape_string($_GET['injId']) : null;


$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

if ($input && isset($input['headers']) && isset($input['data'])) {
    $headers = $input['headers'];
    $dados = $input['data'];
    $Injetora_Numero = $conexao->real_escape_string($input['injId']);
foreach ($dados as $linha) {
    $rowData = array_combine($headers, $linha);

    if (!empty(array_filter($rowData))) {
        $Injetora_Id = isset($rowData['Id']) ? intval($rowData['Id']) : null;
        $Injetora_Data = $conexao->real_escape_string($rowData['Data']);
        $Injetora_Pedido = $conexao->real_escape_string($rowData['Pedido']);
        $Injetora_Quantidade = $conexao->real_escape_string($rowData['Quantidade']);
        $Injetora_Peca = $conexao->real_escape_string($rowData['Peça']);
        $Injetora_OP_Codigo = $conexao->real_escape_string($rowData['Vincular OP']);

        if ($Injetora_Id) {
            $sql = "UPDATE injetora SET 
                    Injetora_Data='$Injetora_Data', 
                    Injetora_Pedido='$Injetora_Pedido', 
                    Injetora_Quantidade='$Injetora_Quantidade', 
                    Injetora_Peca='$Injetora_Peca', 
                    Injetora_OP_Codigo='$Injetora_OP_Codigo',
                    Injetora_Numero='$Injetora_Numero'
                    WHERE Injetora_Id=$Injetora_Id";
        } else {
            $checkDuplicateSql = "SELECT Injetora_Id FROM injetora 
                                WHERE Injetora_Data='$Injetora_Data' 
                                AND Injetora_Pedido='$Injetora_Pedido' 
                                AND Injetora_Quantidade='$Injetora_Quantidade' 
                                AND Injetora_Peca='$Injetora_Peca' 
                                AND Injetora_OP_Codigo='$Injetora_OP_Codigo' 
                                AND Injetora_Numero='$Injetora_Numero'";
            
            $result = $conexao->query($checkDuplicateSql);
            if ($result->num_rows === 0) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO injetora (Injetora_Data, Injetora_Pedido, Injetora_Quantidade, 
                        Injetora_Peca, Injetora_OP_Codigo, Injetora_Numero) 
                        VALUES ('$Injetora_Data', '$Injetora_Pedido', '$Injetora_Quantidade',
                        '$Injetora_Peca', '$Injetora_OP_Codigo', '$Injetora_Numero')";
            }
        }

 

       if ($conexao->query($sql) !== TRUE) {
                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                echo json_encode(['error' => 'Erro ao salvar o registro: ' . $conexao->error]);
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}

// Buscar os dados e retornar como JSON
$query = "SELECT Injetora_Id, Injetora_Data, Injetora_Pedido, 
Injetora_Quantidade, Injetora_Peca, Injetora_OP_Codigo, Injetora_Numero 
        FROM injetora 
        WHERE Injetora_Numero = '$injId'";
$result = $conexao->query($query);

$data = [];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = [
            $row['Injetora_Data'], 
            $row['Injetora_Pedido'], 
            $row['Injetora_Quantidade'], 
            $row['Injetora_Peca'], 
            $row['Injetora_OP_Codigo'],
            $row['Injetora_Id'],
        ];
    }
}

inserir a descrição da imagem aqui

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
